# Counting number of cells with certain word if another cell in that row is not blank

Tags: google-sheets

I have 2 columns, "machine type" and "install date". What I want to do is count the number of machines per type once they are installed. So if there were 3 "Machinetype1" installed 11/29/13, I want another cell to keep that total 3. I don't care what the install date is, as long as it is filled out. In another cell, I will keep the number of "Machinetype2" installed.

Comment: Please let me know if this is not clear.

Comment: Best is to create an example file, with the expected outcome and share that with us.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a layout as shown:

[image: WA52670 example]

please try:

```
=COUNTIFS(B:B,">"&0,A:A,A2)
```

copied down to C4.

Where there are many machine types and/or the first entries in ColumnA do not serve as they do in the image, either create a list of machine types and use the location of the top of that list instead of A2 or simply copy the whole way down regardless and accept that the result for that machine type will be shown on every row for that machine type (eg C9:C11 as another 'set' and C12 as an individual).